# includegraphics throw error with eps file

Tags: graphics, errors, miktex, texstudio

I want to use the ACM Latex proceeding template available at:

http://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template

I have downloaded all the needed files that are defined on the LaTeX2e section, and using TexStudio 2.5.2; the installation came with the MikTex (I think that is well written if not sorry for that).

The problem is that when I want to run the example using the double arrow, compile and view, all the time is giving me this error:

```
File `flies' not found. \includegraphics{flies}
File `rosette' not found. ...egraphics[height=1in, width=1in]{rosette}
```

so the question is why does not recognize those eps files if they are in the same directory? I have seen some solutions around here, but I have not work it around.

Comment: I think that when you press the arrows it is running `pdflatex` instead of `latex`. `pdflatex` does not accept eps figures. You can change to run `latex`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Another option would be using pstool instead of includegraohics